# clickhouse не создает sessions через dbeaver

Tags: сессия, jdbc, clickhouse, dbeaver

Для работы с временными таблицами нужно подключить сессию.
В свойствах драйвера через dbeaver указываю session_id и session_timeout, но
при запросе `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE...` все равно получаю
ошибку `There is no session or session context has expired.` как будто никакой сессии и не создается. если в свойствах драйвера менять, например, базу данных, то изменения применяются.

если напрямую через http-интерфейс выполняю запрос, указывая session_id и session_timeout, то временная таблица создается, но хочется все же по привычному работать

```
http://host:port/?user=user&password=password&session_id=session_id&session_timeout=600&database=database&query=CREATE%20TEMPORARY%20TABLE...
```

в чем может быть причина? где копать, что искать?

Драйвер стандартный кликхауса com.clickhouse:clickhouse-jdbc:RELEASE 0.3.2
clickhouse 22.9.3.18
dbeaver 22.2.1.202209251341
у меня полная роль

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с подобной проблемой, необходимо выполнить запрос:
CREATE TEMPORARY...

Во вкладке настройка соединения - свойства драйвера выставил значения:
session_id=1
session_timeout=600

Скрипт успешно выполняется

Версия dbeaver community: 21.0.0.202102281712
Версия драйвера clickhouse-jdbc: 0.2.6
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, переведите ваш ответ на русский язык.

Comment: исправить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

dbeaver не создает сессию и не позволяет менять настройки в рамках сессии

стоит пользоваться clickhouse-client для изменения настроек в рамках сессии

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].